# How to handler an error of MKDirectionsRequest

Tags: swift, error-handling, crash, mkdirection

I'm not very familiar with error handling and so any advice would be really appreciated.

My code makes multiple calls recursively to the Apple API for calculating a route as it needs to calculate the distance for multiple options.

```
do { 
    directions.calculate(completionHandler: {(response, error) in


     let response =  (response?.routes)! //This line bugs out

     for route in response {

            //code

     completion(result, error)
     }
    })
}
catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

It tends to crash on the 5th or 6th time, and I wondered if there was a way to stop the application crashing and notify instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in using a `do-catch` block, since there's no `throwable` function in your code, so you won't be able to catch any errors. In Swift you can only catch errors thrown by a function marked `throws`, all other errors are unrecoverable.

You should safely unwrap the optional `response`, since it might be `nil`, in which case the force unwrapping would cause an unrecoverable runtime error that you have already been experiencing.

You can use a `guard` statement and optional binding to safely unwrap the optional `response` and exit early in case there's no `response`.

```
directions.calculate(completionHandler: {(response, error) in
    guard let response = response, error == nil else {
        completion(nil,error)
        return
    }

     for route in response.routes {
         ....
         completion(result, nil)
     }
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much this makes sense and solved the issue!